# Simulate Enter Press in a Screen

Tags: scripts

I have successfully run command

```
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

in the terminal and had screen Run receive the stop command and then receive the simulated enter press. This results in the program running in that screen terminating. However when I try to make a script which looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
  screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

the screen revives the text

```
-X: stuff: invalid option stop-ne
```

I would like to know what is wrong with my script and how to correct it so screen Run receives the stop command and then receives an enter press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sh` version of echo does not support options.

Change your script to be run with Bash like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop'"$(echo -ne '\015')"
```

Alternatively, just put a literal newline in the string instead of relying on `echo`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop
'
```

Comment: Thx worked perfectly

Comment: Hey sry but it seems to only receive "stop-ne"

Comment: Thx i got it to work

Comment: @Ethan In my answer, I have put an "Alternatively" section. Try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop^M'
```

Comment: Sry but no the srceen just receives 'stop^M"

Comment: Use a literal ctrl-m, not a caret followed by an M.  You can also use '\r', which I have just tested and confirmed to be working.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @kiri has provided, you can also just use the new line escape code `\n` instead of making a new literal line.

Using the literal new line:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop
'
```

Using the escape character:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
screen -S Run -X stuff 'stop\n'
```